# Loading background image from CSS file in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css

I have a simple html file with a simple css file that just displays the image of a playing card if I load the html file using chrome the playing card is displayed.  However, if I load the same html file using WebView there is no image.  If I just set a background color then that works fine so the html and the css are loaded correctly and working, so I'm assuming the problem is with the url for the image.  Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks,

John

assets
  game.html
  gamecss3.css
  images
      ssk.png

Java code

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game.html");
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #aaa;
}
/* defines styles for each card */
.card {
  width: 72px;
  height: 96px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: url("images/ssK.png");
  /*background: #efefef; */
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;  
}
```

HTML
    
    
    
      
      Simple Card Game

## Card Game

```
  <section id="game">
    <div id="cards">
      <div id="card1" class="card"></div>
    </div> <!-- #cards -->
  </section> <!-- #game -->
  <footer>
    <p>This is an example of transitioning cards.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you answered it, I also guess the problem is in the path to image file

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The image url is not being found. If you have a webhost, upload it to that and change the paths in your CSS & HTML respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the image files and then use `webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl(...)` thingy..